# Как зайти в админку после переноса через duplicator?

Tags: wordpress

После переноса сайта через плагин duplicator не получается зайти в админку. Во время перехода в админ панель пишет Not Found. Как исправить эту проблему подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: С duplicator проблем не бывает, что-то вы сделали не так. Похоже на неправильный .htaccess.

Comment: Кто пишет?..........

Comment: @KAGGDesign подскажите пожалуйста как должен быть правильно выглядеть .htaccess?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Comment: @KAGGDesign Заменил на правильный htaccess. Всё равно проблема присутствует :(